# Laravel get session not returning an anything

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i am learning laravel, and i am using Auth::login on signup and Auth::attempt on login, i logged in and i am doing the following in my master layout (using blade php)

```
        @if(!Auth::check())
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        @endif
        @if(Auth::check())
            <li><a href="{{ route('news') }}">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">{{ session()->get('username') }}</a></li>
        @endif
```

as you probably have noticed this is for the menu, when i am logged out i only get the Home menu and when i am logged in i only get News and Admin, i am trying to set display the users username in the menu aswell which will route to profile (not yet created)

i am sincerely sorry if i made a stupid mistake, im good at php but i am still very new to laravel and MVC in general

Comment: i also tried `Session::get('username')` same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your session management code, your username might not be present in the Session facade. The default way of getting your user's data after login is to use: `Auth::user()`.

If a user has the public attribute `username`, you'll be able to get it through

```
Auth::user()->username
```

By the way, it would also be good to use `@else` instead of checking again for inverse Auth::check() condition

Comment: it is working thank you for the good explanation, so for sessions why would i use them if there is Auth::user ? and yes i ended up using this `@if(Auth::guest())
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                @else
                    <li><a href="{{ route('news') }}">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">{{ Auth::user()->username }}</a></li>
                @endif`

Comment: Sessions could be used to store temporary data about your users, such as the last visited page or something like that. The data could then also be stored in the database for future usage or simply be destroyed when the session ends. Little more reading about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/session :)

Comment: Awesone thank you, ive used sessions using pdo before but only for user info to check if logged in. Laravel is magic lol

Comment: It is, really! I love it and you're merely starting to see the possibilities. I would strongly recommend listening to the first Get started Laracasts videos if you're still just starting. It's worth it, thrust me! :)

Comment: Thank you! i am following a youtube tutorial playlist but the guy is using laravel 5.2 so i have to google all the changes between 5.2 and 5.3 and i am surprised there is a lot

Comment: i have another question if you dont mind me asking, i am using redirect()->route('home', ['message','The invite Code is invalid'])

Comment: so what i am doing in my controller is this :

Comment: `$match_code = DB::table('codes')->where('code', $code)->pluck('code');

        if($code == $match_code){

            $ip->save();

            $user->save();

            Auth::login($user);

            return redirect()->route('news');

        }else{

            return redirect()->route('home')->with('message','Invite Code is invalid');

        }`

Comment: now in my home view i am trying to get that message back if it is set, can u help me ? thank you

Comment: by the way, i used with() didnt put it in the route()

Comment: Sorry, not on my computer anymore :) Gonna take a look tomorrow. But I can already tell you that using `DB::` in your controllers is not good practice. Just take a peek at Laracasts, they're really great to get good (not only with Laravel, but even PHP and MVC)

Comment: k thank you, and sorry for bombarding you with comments

Comment: No problem at all! My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `Auth::guest()` instead of `Auth::check()` for this case.

For example:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    // Code that a guest can see, in your case que Home
@else
    // Code that a logged in user can see
@endif
```

For me it worked pretty good!

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thats not the issue

Comment: I cant see the session